# Host spring boot api using aws lambda

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have one simple controller which returns hell word and I want to host it on aws lambda am trying to hot the application but not getting any proper documentation how to deploy app using aws lambda all documentations have some RequestStreamHandler hander so how will controller will de called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda do not respond to URL so the controller will **NOT** be called. I don't know any ways to get Spring Boot responding to Lambda invocation other than `RequestHandler`

As far as I know there is no HTTP information in Lambda (except metadata that you would pass into the JSON from i.e. API Gateway)

There is btw a starter for AWS Lambda in cloud function. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/aws.html